# How to add CSRF cookie directive?

Tags: csrf, cookies

I need to add the `SameSite` directive to my site's CSRF cookie, as explained in these [mozilla security guidelines](https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/web_security#directives-2). According to the [Craft docs](https://craftcms.com/guides/enabling-csrf-protection), "Craft handles the cookie creation automatically." Is there a way I can configure the cookie?

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible but it's a little bit difficult for beginners. You'll need make use of [Service Locators](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-service-locator) and overwrite `craft\web\Response` to change this method

```PHP
foreach ($this->getCookies() as $cookie) {
    $value = $cookie->value;
    if ($cookie->expire != 1 && isset($validationKey)) {
        $value = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->hashData(serialize([$cookie->name, $value]), $validationKey);
    }
    setcookie($cookie->name, $value, $cookie->expire, $cookie->path, $cookie->domain, $cookie->secure, $cookie->httpOnly);
}
```

`setcookie` is the key here, because if you use it like that, you can't really include the parameter, so you need call it accordingly with [options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

```PHP
setcookie ( string $name [, string $value = "" [, array $options = [] ]] ) : bool
```

Each `yii\web\Cookie` only has the following Attributes

```PHP
public $name;
public $value = '';
public $domain = '';
public $expire = 0;
public $path = '/';
public $secure = false;
public $httpOnly = true;
```

Since there is no `sameSite` attribut you have to think about an intelligent way to set it. There is already a [feature request](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/14742) for it. Maybe it's easier to ask about the current status.

Comment: Ah thanks. I'll probably monitor the feature request.